# Pycharm: run only part of my Python file

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to run only a part of a program in PyCharm?

In other editors there is something like a cell which I can run, but I can't find such an option in PyCharm?

If this function doesn't exist it would be a huge drawback for me... Because for my data analysis I very often only need to run the last few lines of my code.

Comment: You can use Jupyter notebook inside pyCharm. Just select new Jupyter notebook

Comment: Is it possible to run only a part of a program in PyCharm? Yes. You can refer to the following website: [enter link description here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/04/pycharm-scientific-mode-with-code-cells/)

Answer (score 146):

I found out an easier way.

- go to File -> Settings -> Keymap
- Search for `Execute Selection in Console` and reassign it to a new shortcut, like <kbd>Crl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is the same shortcut to the same action in Spyder and R-Studio.

Comment: Very glad you added this answer! I'm sure all RStudio and Spyder users will appreciate this

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to select the code section everytime ? For example in Spyder, we can write "#%%" at the beginning and end of the code section and we can execute it in console with Ctrl+Enter without having to select it.

Comment: @kanmani have a look at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode it does what you ask for

Comment: Notice: despite the name "Execute Selection in Console", pointing the cursor to anywhere in the line and using this action will execute current line.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for running a selection in the terminal?

Answer (score 71):

Pycharm shortcut for running "Selection" in the console is ALT + SHIFT + e

*For this to work properly, you'll have to run everything this way.*

[image]

Answer (score 25):

You can select a code snippet and use right click menu to choose the action "Execute Selection in console".

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, since all the variables which are defined before my code snippet aren't in the workspace anymore.

Comment: @FrankTheTank You need to highlight all the appropriate code, including any imports. It's basically a copy-paste shortcut.

Answer (score 17):

You can set a breakpoint, and then just open the debug console. So, the first thing you need to turn on your debug console:

[image]

After you've enabled, set a break-point to where you want it to:

[image]

After you're done setting the break-point:

[image]

Once that has been completed:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to File >> Settings >> Plugins and install the plugin `PyCharm cell mode`
2. Go to File >> Settings >> Appearance & Behavior >> Keymap and assign your keyboard shortcuts for `Run Cell` and `Run Cell and go to next`

A cell is delimited by ##

**Ref**
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode

Answer (score 2):

### Using Code Cells in .py file in PyCharm

You can achieve a similar experience of running only specific parts of a Python file or treating it like a notebook in PyCharm by following these steps:

1. If you have the PyCharm Professional edition:

   - From the main menu, go to **View | Scientific mode**.
   - This enables the Scientific mode in PyCharm, which provides additional functionality like code cells.
   - You can now use **`#%%`** to delimit a new cell in your Python file.
   - Simply place your code after one of these delimiters to define individual cells.
2. If you are using the PyCharm Community edition:

   - Since the Scientific mode is only available in the Professional edition, you can use a plugin called "PyCharm cell mode" to achieve similar functionality.
   - Install the plugin by going to **Settings | Plugins** (or use the shortcut **`Ctrl + Alt + S`**), then search for "PyCharm cell mode" and install it, or use this [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode).
   - After installation, you can use "##" to delimit a new cell in your Python file (you can customize this in plugin settings)
   - Just like before, enclose your desired code within these delimiters to define separate cells.

By following these steps, you'll be able to isolate and execute specific sections of your Python file as if they were individual cells in a notebook. This can be helpful for experimenting with different code snippets or analyzing specific parts of your script.

##### Here's an example to demonstrate what you can expect.

[image: you can expect]

#### How to run cells with a shortcut

**Option 1: Use the default shortcut.**

Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `A`, then type "Run Cell" in the search bar. It will show you the existing shortcut for "Run Cell" or "Run Cell and Select Below" if there is one set, or you can configure a new one from there.

**Option 2: Configure a new one.**

Press `ctrl` + `alt` + `S` to open the settings. Then, search for "keymap" in the search bar. In the keymap settings, find the "Run Cell" or "Run Cell and Select Below" command. now you can configure a new one according to your preference like `ctrl` + `Enter` or `shift` + `Enter`

Comment: then how to run the cells individually just like Ctrl + Enter in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: **Option 1: Use the default shortcut.**

Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `A`, then type "Run Cell" in the search bar. It will show you the existing shortcut for "Run Cell" or "Run Cell and Select Below" if there is one set, or you can configure a new one from there.

**Option 2: Configure a new one.**

Press `ctrl` + `alt` + `S` to open the settings. Then, search for "keymap" in the search bar. In the keymap settings, find the "Run Cell" or "Run Cell and Select Below" command. now you can configure a new one according to your preference like `ctrl` + `Enter` etc..

check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There is an option that you can run jupyter notebook file and its cells in pycharm.
For more information visit  [Run and debug Jupyter notebook code cells in pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-jupyter-notebook-cells.html#variables).

Answer (score 0):

For new users, please try to stick to the default Alt+Shift+E. It is much more efficient to be able to execute code with one hand so the other will be free to select the next chunk of codes. Don't get to used to Shift/Ctrl + Enter from other IDE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Pycharm Professional you can use *scientific mode*, it does exactly the same as in Spyder:

```
In the Scientific mode you can format your code as a set of executable 
cells to run each separately. To split your code into cells just add # %% 
lines where appropriate.
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

Cells are then executed with `ctrl + enter`

(And if you are registered at a University or possibly other educational facility, you can get a free Professional license from jetbrains)