# Execute code-section in pycharm

Tags: python, matlab, pycharm

I'm moving from Matlab to Python (using Pycharm) and I'm looking for an equivalent way to creating sections in my script (using '%%' in the beginning of the line to create a new section in Matlab) and run them separately with 'ctrl+enter'). 
Selection the lines I want to run and click 'Execute Section in Console' is NOT the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm: run only part of my Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441657/pycharm-run-only-part-of-my-python-file)

Comment: IMHO Spyder is a better IDE, for someone transitioning from Matlab to Python. It has very similar functionality to Matlab, albeit not as good as Matlab. Just like Matlab, to run section of your code, you can wrap your code in a cell and run it.

Comment: @kedarps That's exactly what I'm looking for - creating sections in my code. I know Spyder supports this possibility but I prefer Pycharm anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The feature of using #%% as code separator is now available in PyCharm 2018 (only in the professional edition, not the yet in the community edition as of 2019).

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/04/pycharm-scientific-mode-with-code-cells/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in debug mode - more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23454826/8517006

Comment: I explained explicitly that I was not looking for this solution.