# Migrating Python code away from Jupyter and over to PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to take advantage of a number of features in PyCharm hence looking to port code over from my Notebooks. I've installed everything but am now faced with issues such as:

1. The Display function appears to fail hence dataframe outputs (used print) are not so nicely formatted. Equivalent function?
2. I'd like to replicate the n number of code cell in a Jupyter notebook. The Jupyter code is split over 9 cells in the one Jupyter file and `shift+ Enter`is an easy way to check outputs then move on. Now I've had to place all the code in the one Project/python file and have 1200 lines of code. Is there a way to section the code like it is in Jupyter? My VBA background envisions 9 routines and one additional calling routine to get the same result.

Each block of code is importing data from SQL Server and some flat files so there is some validation in between running them. I was hoping there was an alternative to manually selecting large chunks of code/executing and/or Breakpoints everytime it's run.

Any thoughts/links would be appreciated. I spent some $$ on Udemy on a PyCharm course but it does not help me with this one.

Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm: run only part of my Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441657/pycharm-run-only-part-of-my-python-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The migration part is solved in this question: [convert json ipython notebook(.ipynb) to .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file), but perhaps you already knew that.

The code-splitting part is harder. One reason to why Jupyter is so widely spread is the functionality to split the output and run each cell separately. I would recommend @Andrews answer though.

If you are using classes put each class in a new file.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Jansson and Andrew. Thanks for the download option. I'll place the code in different classes.