# Pycharm: Is there a way to run a snippet of code without running the entire file?

Tags: python, pycharm, conv-neural-network

I am teaching myself to code Convolutional Neural Networks. In particular I am looking at the "Dogs vs. Cats" challenge (https://medium.com/@mrgarg.rajat/kaggle-dogs-vs-cats-challenge-complete-step-by-step-guide-part-2-e9ee4967b9). I am using PyCharm.

In PyCharm, is there a way of using the trained model to make a prediction on the test data without having to run the entire file each time (and thus retrain the model each time)? Additionally, is there a way to skip the part of the script that prepares the data for input into the CNN? In a similar manner, does PyCharm store variables- can I print individual variables after the script has been run.

Would it be better if I used a different IDLE?

Comment: I'd recommend giving Python debugger within Pycharm a try -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html

Also, there is an "Evaluate Expression" button that lets you run specific parts of your code without running everything -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/evaluating-expressions.html

Comment: I don't have experience with the library you're referring to, but in Pycharm, you can open the interactive console at the bottom ("Python Console"), and run arbitrary code in that. If you load a file into it, you can run code (after the file has loaded). Also note that "IDLE" is a specific IDE.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441657/pycharm-run-only-part-of-my-python-file) what you want ?

Comment: Jupyter Notebooks are probably the way to go (or Jupyter Lab - newer and fairly similar). It's ideal for writing code that you can execute in sections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm: run only part of my Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441657/pycharm-run-only-part-of-my-python-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sklearn joblib](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) to save the trained model as a `pickle` and use it later for predictions.

```py
from sklearn.externals import joblib 

# Save the model as a pickle in a file 
joblib.dump(knn, 'filename.pkl') 

# Load the model from the file 
knn_from_joblib = joblib.load('filename.pkl')  

# Use the loaded model to make predictions 
knn_from_joblib.predict(X_test)
```