Is there similar jupyter interactive shell function in pycharm like in vs code
One feature I like in vs code is its interactive shell where I can just select the code and press shift + enter to run it in jupyter interactive shell. Although pycharm has python console, but it is not as convenient as vs code. I want to write code in pycharm editor, but run it in interactive via some short cut. Is there any way to do that?

I don't use Pycharm - are these methods helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23441657
